# Create Map of Lists?

Tags: go

I have a struct that has an task id, a date, and a comment field similar to this:

```
type Journal struct {
    task_id int
    date  int
    comment string
}
```

For each task_id, I was to create a list of all Journals for that task_id.  Then I'd like to put each Journal List into a map so that I can easily manage each of my task id's.  Here is some sample data:

```
100, 20140701, "Failed to complete"
100, 20140702, "Removed data and finished in 5 minutes"

120, 20140701, "No issues"

130, 20140701, "Called analyst"
130, 20140702, "reloaded data"
130, 20140703, "Emailed results"
```

For now I'm not sure if I need to order the comments beyond knowing which date they occurred.

How do I create the map of Lists?  I haven't seen any examples where I "make" a list.

```
x := make(map[int]Journal)
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: That is a slice, not a list, also keep in mind maps in Go are not ordered. if you want to sort the journal slice, check [this](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_Interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `map` you want with this code:

```
var m = make(map[int][]Journal)
for _, journal := range all_my_journals {
    m[journal.task_id] = append(m[journal.task_id], journal)
}
```

Assuming `all_my_journals` is a slice (or array) of all the `Journal` variables you have.

Then, you can have a slice (and not a list) of all the `Journal`s of a given id:

```
journals := m[my_task_id]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Julienc's excellent answer, if your intention is to be able to sort the journals, you could use a struct that implements [sort.Interface](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_Interface) like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/dYgF_BxZmW):

```
type JournalSorter struct {
    s   []*Journal
    f   func(a, b *Journal) bool
    rev bool
}

func NewSorter(j []*Journal) (js *JournalSorter) {
    js = &JournalSorter{s: make([]*Journal, len(j))}
    for i := range j {
        js.s[i] = j[i]
    }
    return
}
func (js *JournalSorter) ById(reverse bool) []*Journal {
    js.rev = reverse
    js.f = js.byId
    sort.Sort(js)
    return js.s
}

func (js *JournalSorter) ByDate(reverse bool) []*Journal {
    js.rev = reverse
    js.f = js.byDate
    sort.Sort(js)
    return js.s
}

func (js *JournalSorter) byId(a, b *Journal) bool {
    if js.rev {
        return a.Id > b.Id
    }
    return a.Id < b.Id
}

func (js *JournalSorter) byDate(a, b *Journal) bool {
    if js.rev {
        return a.Date > b.Date
    }
    return a.Date < b.Date
}

func (js *JournalSorter) Len() int {
    return len(js.s)
}

func (js *JournalSorter) Swap(i, j int) {
    if js.s != nil && js.f != nil {
        js.s[i], js.s[j] = js.s[j], js.s[i]
    }
}

func (js *JournalSorter) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if js.f != nil {
        return js.f(js.s[i], js.s[j])
    }
    return false
}
///.................

func main() {
    journals := m[my_task_id] //m = map[int][]*Journal
    s1 := NewSorter(journals)
    sorted_by_reverse_date := s1.ByDate(true)
}
```